# ¿Cómo concatenar variable a SELECT en ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, plsql, apex

Tengo un problema en Oracle, soy nuevo en esto y estoy trabajando en la plataforma APEX ORACLE, necesito crear un informe que muestre los datos repetidos en diferentes campos "NIT", "NAME", "TELEPHONE", etc...

[image: PLATAFORMA APEX]

Estoy haciendo una condición bastante extensa para verificar cada campo para validar si tiene datos o es nulo; la consulta es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE
filtro VARCHAR2(16000) :='';
QRY VARCHAR2(16000);
BEGIN

IF (:P18_TODOS is not null) THEN
    filtro:=' NIT, DPI, TELEFONO1,CORREO1 ';
ELSE
    IF (:P18_NIT is not null) THEN 
        filtro:=' NIT';
    END IF;
    
     IF (:P18_DPI is not null) THEN 
         IF filtro = ' NIT ' THEN
             filtro:= filtro||' ,DPI ';
         ELSE 
             filtro:= filtro||' DPI ';
         END IF;
      END IF;
      
      IF (:P18_NOMBRE is not null) THEN 
         IF filtro = ' NIT ' OR filtro = ' DPI ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,DPI ' THEN
             filtro:= filtro||' ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO';
         ELSE 
             filtro:= filtro||' NOMBRE_COMPLETO';
         END IF;
      END IF;
      
       IF (:P18_TELEFONO is not null) THEN 
         IF filtro = ' NIT ' OR filtro = ' DPI ' OR filtro = ' NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,DPI ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,DPI ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' OR filtro = ' DPI ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' THEN
             filtro:= filtro||' ,TELEFONO';
         ELSE 
             filtro:= filtro||' TELEFONO';
         END IF;
      END IF;
      
      IF (:P18_TELEFONO is not null) THEN 
         IF filtro = ' NIT ' OR filtro = ' DPI ' OR filtro = ' NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,DPI ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,DPI ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' OR filtro = ' DPI ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ' 
         OR filtro = ' DPI ,TELEFONO ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,TELEFONO ' OR filtro = ' NOMBRE_COMPLETO ,TELEFONO ' OR filtro = ' NIT ,DPI ,NOMBRE_COMPLETO ,TELEFONO' THEN
             filtro:= filtro||' ,CORREO1';
         ELSE 
             filtro:= filtro||' CORREO1';
         END IF;
      END IF;
      
      
END IF;

QRY := 'SELECT * 
            FROM (
                SELECT
                m."ID", 
                m."NIT", 
                m."DPI",
                m."ULTIMO_CONSUMO", 
                m."NOMBRE_COMPLETO", 
                m."PRIMER_NOMBRE", 
                m."SEGUNDO_NOMBRE", 
                m."PRIMER_APELLIDO",
                m."SEGUNDO_APELLIDO",
                m."TELEFONO1",
                m."TELEFONO2",
                m."CORREO1",
                m."CORREO2", 
                ROWID rid,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                    OVER(PARTITION BY '||filtro ||' ORDER BY ID) rn
                FROM CLIENTES_MASTER m
                ORDER BY 1
                )
            WHERE rn <> 1;';

return QRY;
end;
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: ERROR ORACLE]

Veo mi error al concatenar la variable "filter", al eliminar la concatenación no tengo ningún error y devuelve el valor correcto. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de concatenar una variable en el momento de realizar `ROW NUMBER PARTITION BY`.

[image: SECCION]

Comment: Que se supone que  quieres hacer  con '||filtro||' porque  eso es una constante. Quieres concatenar? Estas concatenando todo  ese query como un string?

Comment: Utiliza CONCAT para ver si te da el error CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT....',filtro),'OVER..'.)

Comment: 1. Publica los mensajes de error como texto, no como imagen, por favor. 2. ¿Has hecho un print para inspeccionar el resultado de la concatenación? ¿Pasa con cualquier combinación de parámetros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al inicializar la constante no se retorna el error, APEX realiza una ejecución del Query al verificar la estructura del mismo, al no poseer valor en la constante no ejecuta el query correctamente.

La solución fue:

```
DECLARE
filtro VARCHAR2(16000) :=' NIT, DPI, TELEFONO1, CORREO1 ';

QRY VARCHAR2(16000);
```